# Loading shapefiles onto leaflet

Tags: javascript, button, leaflet, mapbox, shapefile

I was wondering if there is a plugin for loading a zipped shapefile onto leaflet with the click of a button (or drag and drop) similar to the one found here (http://leaflet.calvinmetcalf.com/#4/48.89/-87.54). Note: I am using version 1.0 of leaflet. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> …loading a zipped shapefile onto leaflet *with the click of a button (or drag and drop)*?

The answer is "no".

The [`leaflet.shapefile` plugin from calvinmetcalf](https://github.com/calvinmetcalf/leaflet.shapefile) allows to load shapefiles, but does *not* handle [file read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) or [drag-and-dropping files](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Selecting_files_using_drag_and_drop).

You'll have to read the file contents yourself, and feed it to `leaflet.shapefile`